# Drawing documentation: Is possible to keep the original drawing valid when revised version is released?

Tags: standards, documentation

is possible (by European standards) to have two (or more) valid drawings with same drawing number but different revision indexes?

For example:

- `DRW-001` = Some Bolt M20x50
- `DRW-001a` = Same bolt but length
  changed (M20x60)

And then BOM(s) where both (DRW-001, DRW-001a) are used for bolts M20x50 respectively M20x60?

I know this is far from good solution, but it is even legal/valid?

(My 6th sense tells since a new revision is released, all previous versions became invalid. But can't find any stamdard citation supporting my feeling.)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Typical ISO practice is the most recently approved and released drawing is valid. A common work around for off the shelf parts, like bolts, is to have one generic *drawing* number for multiple *part* numbers that just lists a table of dimensions for a common part. An example for your bolt:

**DRAWING DRW-0010: BOLT, HEX HEAD, M20**

```
P/N        LENGTH     PITCH
DRW-0011   50         1.5
DRW-0012   50         2
DRW-0013   60         1.5
```

Comment: I agree with typical practice (I use it too, consider it correct), but I'd like to support my feeling by some hard-evidence from some standard. Only what I've found yet is (ČSN) `EN 82045-1` Paragraph `4.5.3` which describes the typical practice. BUT right below is paragraph `4.5.4` which describe opposite system - more than 1 valid revisions in one moment. (I don't have an English version of the standard, so I'm unable to cite it precisely.)